# How can GoToMeeting be used in Ubuntu 20.04 on any browser?

Tags: sound, chromium, microphone

I'm attempting to help someone to access an online video meeting infrastructure called GoToMeeting. It appears to block Firefox and also not to work with Firefox (when a user agent switcher is tried), so this is being attempted on Chromium.

When an attempt to connect to a meeting page is made, no microphone or camera access requests appear to be made. This is with site data cleared, all add-ons disabled etc.

[image]

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: I would be asking the go to company about this.

Answer (score 0):

GoToMeeting is only available for Chrome and Edge but after installing Chrome in Ubuntu 20.04 it directly worked for me and asked for permission to use webcam, microphone and sound. (After that I could use everything.)

Did you check the lock symbol next to the URL? There you can grant the permissions to use video, audio and microphone even if Chrome doesn't ask for it specifically.

Or is it possible that you blocked the sound for Chrome in Ubuntu's sound settings?